# How to get actual width of a block displayed with flex-direction:column properly?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

For Example:

#### HTML

```js
console.log($('.container').width()); // 600px as we defined in css.
console.log($('.list').width()); // 600px

console.log($('.box').eq('-1').position().left + $('.box').outerWidth());
```

```css
body{padding:0;margin:0;}
.container {
  width: 600px;
  backround:#E1BEE7;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height:120px;
  background:#FFCDD2;
}

.box {
  margin:10px;
  flex-shrink:0;
  flex-grow:0;
  flex-basis:auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:100px;
  background: #F44336;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:2rem;
}

.result{
  padding:1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box">8</div>
    <div class="box">9</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is 10 boxes, and each box with 100px width, the actual width of element `.list` should be 1000px not 600px.

I tried to use the following method to get actual width of list: The left position of last child element and its outerWidth

```
console.log($('.box').eq('-1').position().left + $('.box').outerWidth());
```

What I want to know: is there a better method to get actual width of this kind of flexbox element? some better built-in javascript or jquery method exists for this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you'd use `column` and finally have a "row" (well, blocks are wrapping) of blocks? Seems counter-intuitive in your demo :)

Comment: Using `min-width: 600px;` is OK if viewport is larger than your flex container. I doubt it's what you want to achieve though

Comment: @FelipeAls The final goal is a multi-row carousel, I use one row in demo to make question easier:) min-width is not OK, js still can't get actual width of list element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, `scrollWidth` will provide you the dimension you're looking for. The reason that `outerWidth` isn't giving you the total width of the internal elements is that your `.list` element is actually 600px wide. The additional content is *overflowing* its parent, allowing it to display despite being outside of the `.list`.

You can test this by changing the `overflow` property to `hidden` on `.list`:

```css
body{ padding:0; margin:0; }
.container {
  width: 600px;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 120px;
  background: #FFCDD2;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  margin:10px;
  flex-shrink:0;
  flex-grow:0;
  flex-basis:auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:100px;
  background: #F44336;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:2rem;
}

.result{
  padding:1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box">8</div>
    <div class="box">9</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that when you run this, the `.list` element clips the remaining boxes.

Hopefully this helps you understand what is going on in addition to solving the problem for you. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

What I need is just `el.scrollWidth`.

Comment: This is a good answer if you want to include the padding that flexboxes add when the content is shorter than the space available.

Answer (score 2):

Probably more code than you wanted, but you could just sum the width of the elements inside the div, using javascript with jQuery like this:

```
var totalWidth = 0;
$('.box').each(function() {
  totalWidth += $(this).width();

});

$('#msg').html(
  "<p>totalWidth: " + totalWidth + "</p>"
);
```

with a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/yeeqkd2e/4/

or without jQuery

```
var totalWidth = 0;

var cont = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
for (var i = 0, len = cont.length; i < len; i++) {
    totalWidth += cont[i].offsetWidth;
}

document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "<p>totalWidth: " + totalWidth + "</p>";
```

Native Javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/yeeqkd2e/6/

Comment: This is a good answer if you want to exclude the padding that flexboxes add when the content is shorter than the space available.